# How do I read branch coverage reports?

Tags: python, nosetests, coverage.py

[image]

I don't understand what coverage is trying to tell me with Branch missing 1 for Branch 4... What lines of code aren't covered in this case?

Thanks!

Edit:

After some trial and error - I believe the Branch number indicated is the order that the branch appears in the file, where branches include any sort of branching code (try, except, finally blocks and if/elif/else blocks).

Can someone validate this?

Comment: Why don't you get the HTML reports, which show you line-by-line what's covered and not?

Comment: Also, have you read e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/branch.html?

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestions.